# The number of orbits of $\langle\pi\rangle$ on $\Omega$ is $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{d\mid m}f(\pi^d)\varphi(m/d)$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-actions, orbit-stabilizer

Let $\Omega$ be $\Omega= \{1, . . . , n\}$ and let $G$ be $G := \text{Sym}(\Omega)$.

Show:

(a) If $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in G$ generate the same cyclic subgroup of $G$, then $f(\pi_1) = f(\pi_2)$.

(b) Let $\pi ∈ G$ be of order $m$. The number of orbits of $\langle\pi\rangle$ on $\Omega$ is

$$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{d\,\mid\,m}f(\pi^d)\varphi\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)$$

Definition of orbit: Consider a group $G$ acting on a set $X$. The orbit of an element $x$ in $X$ is the set of elements in $X$ to which $x$ can be moved by the elements of $G$.

I'm currently learning for the discrete maths exam and I found this old exam question. Unfortunately I really have no idea where to start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And $f$ is?${}{}$

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. The exercise doesn't specify on this point.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: For $\pi\in\operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$, consider the natural action of $\langle\pi\rangle$ on $\Omega$. Then (Burnside's lemma): 
$\#\text{ of orbits}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m\left|\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^k)\right|$, where $\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^k)=\{i\in\Omega\mid\pi^k(i)=i\}$. Now you are left to reconcile this sum with yours' by means of permutations theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\pi\in\operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$ of order $m$, consider the natural action of $\langle\pi\rangle$ on $\Omega$. Then (Burnside's lemma):
$$\#\text{ of orbits}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m\left|\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^k)\right| \tag 1$$
where $\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^k)=\{i\in\Omega\mid\pi^k(i)=i\}$. If $\gcd(k,m)=d$, then $\pi^k$ fixes the same number of elements of $\Omega$ as $\pi^d$. But there are $\varphi (\frac{m}{d})$ elements $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ such that $\gcd(k,m)=d$. Then:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\sum_{k=1}^m\left|\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^k)\right| &= \sum_{d|m}\varphi\Bigl(\frac{m}{d}\Bigr)\left|\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^d)\right| \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}
Now, plug $(2)$ into $(1)$ and you'll get the claim (b) (with the identification $f(\_)=\left|\operatorname {Fix}(\_)\right|$).

---

**Edit**. The number of orbits in the question is precisely the length of the cycle structure of $\pi$, $c_\pi=(\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{k\text{ slots}},m_1,\dots,m_l)$, where:

- all $m_i$'s are greater than $1$;
- $\sum_{i=1}^lm_i=n-k$;
- $m=\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,\dots,m_l)$.

In particular, if $\pi$ is an $m$-cycle, then:
$$n-m+1=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{d|m}\varphi\Bigl(\frac{m}{d}\Bigr)\left|\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^d)\right| \tag 3$$
which, for $\pi$ an $n$-cycle, further specializes into:
$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{\varphi(n/d)}{n}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(\pi^d)\right|=1 \tag 4$$
Since $\sum_{d|n}\frac{\varphi(n/d)}{n}=1$ (see "**Divisor sum**" under ["Computing Euler's totient function"  section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)), $(4)$ looks like a weigthed average with possibly some statistic application.

(Added: $(4)$ is trivial, actually: in fact, for an $n$-cycle $\pi$, $\left|\operatorname {Fix}(\pi^d)\right|\ne 0\iff d=n$, and $\left|\operatorname {Fix}(\pi^n)\right|=\left|\operatorname {Fix}(Id)\right|=n$, whence $(4)$ trivially follows.)